# how to pass a process thread handle to another process

Tags: windows, multithreading, process, apc

I need to pass a thread handle for APC to another process in order to be able to call QueueUserAPC into the src thread :

HANDLE SMconsumerThread;

```
if (!DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(),// src server thread
                       GetCurrentThread(),
                       GetCurrentProcess(),// target is any client
                       (HANDLE*)&SMconsumerThread,
                       THREAD_SET_CONTEXT, // only permission required by QueueUserAPC
                       FALSE, // not inheritable
                       0)) // no options
{
    printf("cannot server thread handle");
}
```

how is it done, because GetCurrentProcess/GetCurrentThread return the pseudo handle -1 within the caller process, I found this explanation for passing sockets among processes: http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/articles/passing-sockets.html

are there any examples or explanations how to duplicate a thread handle ?

Comment: Shouldn't you specify the target process handle?

Comment: the problem is I don't know before hand who is the target process, I want to make known a single permanent thread of a db server to ANY client, which have different pids, exe names, not knowable beforehand, they just connect to the server with IPC and I need to pass to the client the thread handle of the server so the client can issue user APC to the server to do server side transactions.

Comment: A handle is only usable in a specific process. You *must* duplicate it into the target. Change your architecture so that you can get a handle to any client.

Comment: if I obtain the client process handle like this : HANDLE Hclient= OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, GetCurrentProcessId ()); and pass it to the server (via ipc) to call DuplicateHandle on server side with the 3rd argument target handle as Hclient ?

Comment: If the client obtains a handle to itself that handle is not valid to the parent. You can send the numeric value of the handle but it is meaningless to any other process. Send the PID. Be aware that this is a security issue because a client might lie about the PID. Is there no other way to obtain a handle to the client process? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365440(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The MSDN Library article for QueueUserAPC() very strongly recommends against doing this.  This will work only by chance.

Comment: client side :   HANDLE myself= (HANDLE)GetCurrentProcessId();

server side:

HANDLE client= OpenProcess(PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, FALSE, (DWORD)m_SMClientPid);// m_SMClientPid has been read from shared memory

if (!DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(),// src server process

GetCurrentThread(),// src server thread

client,// target is any client

(HANDLE*)&SMNewconsumerThread,    
   
THREAD_SET_CONTEXT, // only permission required by QueueUserAPC

FALSE, // not inheritable

DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS)) // same access as server

{

 LastError("cannot obtain db thread id to pass to client");

}

Comment: this should in theory make the server side current thread handle SMNewconsumerThread usable by the client which will read the 
handle from shared mem ?

Comment: supposing I now have the server thread handle available in the client, how could I specify which function to run server side : QueueUserAPC(SMAPCEvent, DBFifo.m_SMAPCthread, DBFifo.m_SMclientslot);

Comment: My expertise is exhausted. But as said by Hans the docs to QueueUserAPC tell you why this can't reliably work. The function address is unreliable and there's nothing you can do about it. Drop QueueUserAPC and do something else. Can't you just use some more standard technique like pipes to transfer data?

Comment: I put a function pointer in the client : void (CALLBACK *m_SMAPCEvent) (ULONG_PTR context); which is loaded by ipc with the address from the server, the reason I'm not using named pipes is that APC seems a bit faster than named pipes in waking the consumer server.

Comment: Ok that makes sense now.